# Starting Google Chrome from the command line with a blank page

Tags: google-chrome

How can I start Google Chrome with a blank page from the command line (`chrome.exe`)?

Comment: check the default load page and make blank then use chrome.exe to launch.

Comment: I'd like to point you to the [FAQ#etiquette] where it says, *> Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated.* This is your last warning. Don't be rude against community members.

Comment: correct, but downvoting a question without a reason... isn't civil

Comment: @user698585 people may have their reasons. Most popular reason is "does not show research effort". And your question might fall into the catogory a google search could have solved on its own.

Comment: Walter: The question has been asked precisely because a google search didn't yield satisfactory results and by the way the stackexchange administration itself urges users to clearly comment on their downvote reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the command line, simply type:

```
chrome.exe -homepage "about:blank"
```